# Angular5 and Google Maps v3 Api - Getting coordinations from map "click" event

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get coordinations from click event on map

Heres the result im trying to get: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_events_infowindow2)

As far here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-map',
  templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  markers: Array<Object>
  myLatLng = { lat: 53.131083, lng: 23.154742 };
  latitude: 53.131083;
  longitute: 23.154742;
  googleMap: google.maps.Map;

  ngOnInit() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(53.131083, 23.154742);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
      this.placeMarker(event);
    });
  }

  placeMarker(event) {

    //-------------- i can't get map coords -------------
    var eventLatLng = { lat: event.clientX, lng: event.clientY };
    console.log(eventLatLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: this.myLatLng,
      map: this.googleMap
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Marker Location:' + marker.getPosition()
    });

    infowindow.open(this.googleMap, marker);
  }

  addBicycleLayer() {
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(this.googleMap);
  }

  setMapType(mapTypeId: string) {
    this.googleMap.setMapTypeId(mapTypeId)
  }


  setCenter(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.googleMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitute));
  }
}
```

HTML component:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:600px" (click)="placeMarker($event)">
</div>
```

I don't know how to get to the map coordinations. These coords that are in placeMarker function are just client coords ( not integrated with Maps )
I found some https://angular-maps.com/ but it will be a large project and i don't want to rely on this.
I will be grateful for any help :)

Cheers

Comment: Looking at the Google Maps JS API, shouldn't you be using `event.latLng` to get the coords in placeMarker(event)  (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MouseEvent )?

Comment: Tried, in easy-language, angular don't know what event.latLng is, it shows me an error in Firefox (event.latLng you are talking about is here : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_events_infowindow2 and i want to get same result

Comment: I can add marker from coords that i put myself in the code, but its hard to make it via click event and get it from the map

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you're trying to get the coordinates form a click event, i.e. the event object, correct? If so, what error does Firefox show for `event.latLng`? If not can you please further explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: I want to get latitude and longitude from map to make a marker, from "click" event.  ( I will click on the map, get coordinations of i.e New York street and make marker on the map ). After changing code to event.latLng ( see "position" in var marker)and clicking on the map i get this error : https://ibb.co/hsESGm

Comment: Remove the  `(click)="placeMarker($event)"` from the element. You already have the click element attached to the map object, there is no need to create a click element on the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, remove the `(click)="placeMarker($event)"` as it's not what you want to be doing.

Try logging `this` in the click event. It is likely not the context you are after. Instead you should use the fat arrow to pass the correct context to your function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.googleMap, 'click', (event) => {
  this.placeMarker(event);
});
```

Now you should have the correct `event` in the placeMarker function. You should be able to call the latlng from the `event`

Comment: As you said i removed click event and changed addListener function, but now after clicking on the map nothing happens

Comment: change the listner object to `this.googleMap` I'll update my answer to reflect

Comment: Also your `eventLatLng` will fail now in the `placeMarker` event. This is because you are now getting a google event instead of the click event. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: I think that position: event.LatLng, should work but it says its undefined

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(event) ?

Comment: Strange objects : https://ibb.co/hO2pwm . Where im clicking, coordinations should be around {53.12 ,21.15}. latLng are empty
and after i do console.log(event.LatLng) it says its undefined.
Another pic : https://ibb.co/gOrA2R

Comment: case is important. It's not LatLng, it is latLng. You want `event.latLng.lat()` and `event.latLng.lng()`

Comment: Oh my god! Its working!! Thank you so much for your help :D ! Is there anything i can do for you?

Comment: You've already accepted the answer. So it's all good. Good luck with the rest of the work.

Comment: Could you explain me/ navigate me somewhere that I'll uderstand why your addListener function  with this arrow worked and my first one doesnt?

Comment: Also look up fat arrow and lexical scoping in typescript

Comment: Essentially you have to ask yourself what does 'this' refer too? The `placeMarker` function is a callback, and does not share the scope of your component. It has a different `this` and you can confirm it by reinstating your old code and console.log(this). The fat arrow function passes your scope to the callback, so that (this) is maintained.

Answer (score 2):

After [Jags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073800/jags)
help i found the answer!
Here is complete and working code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-map',
  templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  markers: Array<Object>
  myLatLng = { lat: 53.131083, lng: 23.154742 };
  latitude: 53.131083;
  longitute: 23.154742;
  googleMap: google.maps.Map;

  ngOnInit() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(53.131083, 23.154742);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.googleMap, 'click', (event) => {
      this.placeMarker(event);
    });
  }

  placeMarker(event) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: this.googleMap
    });
    console.log(event.latLng.lat() +" "+ event.latLng.lng());
  }

  addBicycleLayer() {
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(this.googleMap);
  }

  setMapType(mapTypeId: string) {
    this.googleMap.setMapTypeId(mapTypeId)
  }


  setCenter(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.googleMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitute));
  }
}
```

[Here is a picture of working code :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAu0r.jpg)